# Calculate time interval in a view for day staff and night shift employees

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime

**Problem**

Hello, Everyone.

I need some help to calculate time interval between check in and check out of employees work on day and night shift. Below is table structure and desired results from the query. Can anyone help?

**Check in and out table:**

```
EventTime   User    Status  Date
12/30/2017 6:38 User 1  Exit    12/30/2017
12/29/2017 18:18    User 1  Entry   12/29/2017
12/29/2017 17:14    User 4  Exit    12/29/2017
12/29/2017 9:14 User 4  Entry   12/29/2017
12/29/2017 18:23    User 2  Exit    12/29/2017
12/29/2017 6:33 User 2  Entry   12/29/2017
12/30/2017 6:38 User 3  Exit    12/30/2017
12/29/2017 18:18    User 3  Entry   12/29/2017
```

**Desired Results:**

```
User    Entry   Exit    Time duration   Date
User 1  12/29/2017 18:18    12/30/2017 6:38 12:19:56    12/29/2017
User 2  12/29/2017 6:33 12/29/2017 18:23    11:49:52    12/29/2017
User 3  12/29/2017 18:18    12/30/2017 6:38 12:19:56    12/29/2017
User 4  12/29/2017 9:14 12/29/2017 17:14    8:00:00 12/29/2017
```

Comment: You tagged both mysql and sql server. Which one are you using?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? The answer will be product specific here.

Comment: it is SQL server. my apologise

Comment: Is there only one entry and one exit for every user? Or can there be more?

Comment: yes there is only one entry and one exit for every user.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is one approach

```
select t.[User], max(case when t.[status] = 'Entry' then t.EventTime end) [Entry],
                 max(case when t.[status] = 'Exit' then t.EventTime end) [Exist],
                 cast(cast(max(case when t.[status] = 'Exit' then t.EventTime end) as datetime) - 
                 cast(max(case when t.[status] = 'Entry' then t.EventTime end) as datetime) as time) [Time duration],
                 max(case when t.[status] = 'Entry' then t.[date] end) [Date]
from table t
group by t.[User]
```

**Note** : In above the datetime used as varchar type since exlicitly needs some casting to datateime. so, avoid it.

Result :

```
User    Entry               Exist            Time duration      Date
User 1  12/29/2017 18:18    12/30/2017 6:38  12:20:00.0000000   12/29/2017
User 2  12/29/2017 6:33     12/29/2017 18:23 11:50:00.0000000   12/29/2017
User 3  12/29/2017 18:18    12/30/2017 6:38  12:20:00.0000000   12/29/2017
User 4  12/29/2017 9:14     12/29/2017 17:14 08:00:00.0000000   12/29/2017
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for you ...

```
  SELECT EntryDtls.UserName,
          EntryDtls.EventTime        AS Entry,
          ExitDtls.EventTime         AS ExitDt,
          CAST(DATEDIFF(second, EntryDtls.EventTime, ExitDtls.EventTime) / 
          60 / 60 % 24  AS NVARCHAR(50))  +':'+
          CAST(DATEDIFF(second, EntryDtls.EventTime, ExitDtls.EventTime) / 
          60 % 60 AS NVARCHAR(50))  +':'+
          CAST(DATEDIFF(second, EntryDtls.EventTime, ExitDtls.EventTime) % 
          60 AS NVARCHAR(50))                                         AS 
          Time_duration,
          EntryDtls.Date
          FROM   (SELECT  *
          FROM  Trans_Tab
          WHERE Status = 'Entry')  AS EntryDtls
          JOIN   (SELECT  *
          FROM  Trans_Tab
          WHERE Status = 'Exit')  AS ExitDtls
          ON     (EntryDtls.UserName        =      ExitDtls.UserName)
```